# is using codeigniter view layer as is without a templating engine for a mdeium sizeapp sane

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, template-engine

I am working on a medium sized app and i have around 30 views to serve in all. I am just using the codeigniters view layer without any template engine integration like smarty and stuff. For me this works best as its simple and easy. But all around the web i see people going cray about using template engine in their views which made me think am i sane enough to just use the codeigniters view layer for an app like this.

So far i havent run into any problems other than using some (sometimes a lot) conditionals in certain views. But if there are any one who ve used just the codeigniters view layer for apps currently in production id love to hear their story. I am almost done with this app and might move to production if i feel that wat i ve done is sane enough.

Ive already seen in SO that people suggesting smarty or williamconcepts template engine to go with codeigniter but all i wanna hear is am i good to go with the native view layer of CI.

Comment: If it works - don't touch it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion templates are old school now ...

Codeigniter's user guide first page says you may want CI if

*You do not want to be forced to learn a templating language (although a template parser is optionally available if you desire one).*

Personally I have found using templates annoying in development (used smarty a long time back), they have a different syntax and they can't be debugged using a debugger.

Now as you asked, yes I have used a very high traffic eCommerce portal and it worked without issues for a good amount of traffic. To further improve the response we implemented memcached later which too worked like charm !

Answer (score 1):

You are good to go with the standard codeigniter view layer if it does the job for you. Then it's even sane to use it.

Otherwise you must know that other solutions have their cons as well so, you might only replace one problem with another one - something which is **insane** close to going live.

Especially if those suggestion come from people you do not even personally know. Like: don't use codeigniter use zend framework instead. This won't help you to get things done on your end, which is most important for you I guess.